# Modify array values in a file

Tags: php

I have a php file with some arrays in it. I want to modify one of these arrays and write it back to the file. For e.g. say file test.php has contents -

```
<?php
$arr1 = array("a"=>"b", "c" =>"d");
$arr2 = array("a2" => "b2", "c2" => "d2");
```

i want to change $arr1 so that test.php now looks like -

```
<?php
$arr1 = array("a"=>"b", "c" =>"d", "e"=>"f");
$arr2 = array("a2" => "b2", "c2" => "d2");
```

I do not know what arrays are present in the file beforehand.

Edit: i am not adding any variables to the array, only another key value pair. The problem is that the array is part of a file with more arrays in it about which I won't always be aware. I can achieve this if there was only one array in the file, but want to know if it is possible to do this with multiple arrays.

Comment: It's hard to understand your context from your question.  You are trying to add unknown variables to the end of the first array?  Or you are trying to determine the contents of the first array based off of how the second changes?  Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish - provided the context of the goal of the script might help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. From my question, it is very clear that i am trying to add a value (not a variable) to the second array. I don't see any reason for a confusion or a downvote here..

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't issue the downvote.  I was not sure from your question how you were accessing this other file.  Is it included or is it being read remotely?

Comment: The array is not using integer key, what is the problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are within a function (i.e. not in global scope) [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) might be a good bet. You'd just need to include the file in a closed scope and return it's keys to get all variable names in the file.

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce another "global" array

```
$arr = array('arr1' => array("a"=>"b", "c" =>"d"), 'arr2' =>("a2" => "b2", "c2" => "d2"));
```

and [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it

```
$serArr = serialize($arr);
//write to file here
```

When you read the file, just [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) its content so you have the "global" array with it's sub-arrays, modify the values you need, serialize it and write it back.

Keep in mind that this can be a huge performance issue when you write big arrays.

Comment: +1.. the method is good but the problem is that i cannot change the file contents to add another array (otherwise it would be very less effort to add the value to the array itself). is there any way i can retrieve all array values from the file and change them and write them back?

Comment: How do you mean "cannot change the file contents to add another array"?

Comment: If by 'changing the values within the file' you mean saving their new values to the file after the request has finished and the script has executed then the only feasible answer would be to save using any mechanism, such as to a flat text file the way DrColossos has described or to a database for later retrieval.  Is this what you mean by changing the file?  You want to actually modify the physical values reflected in test.php, as it write them out in the code permanently and preserve them?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr1 = array("a"=>"b", "c" =>"d");
$newarr=array("d"=>"f");
$arr1+=$newarr;
```

it's has been 5 years, but i want to give simple way that work for me.